# How to get complete product information from Bar code display value in android?

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner, google-vision

I used Google vision Barcode API for scanning the bar code.
From that, I can able to get display value from the bar code. But, how can I get complete product information after scanning the bar code?

Which means, After scanning I'm getting bar code value as 036000291452.
But I need to get product information from it as well.

Similar to below:

Barcode Formats: UPC 036000291452
Artist: Haindling
Label: Polydor

Please help!

Answer (score 7):

To get product information you'll need to use some database of products that's searchable by UPC.  A quick google search came up with a few suggestions, such as https://www.barcodelookup.com/api .

Comment: Hm, I used some random Barcode of a bottle and got no result. Some random barcode scan app told me what it was, so not useful apparently

Comment: but its paid, not free

Answer (score 0):

There are many API's available depending on your needs.
`upcFood.com` has a very accurate database. We use it for our KA SafeFood App.